# Why is the background image getting offset?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a background image which should be displayed with full width and for that I'm calculating the height with javascript.

Here's the HTML. The container is necessary for other purposes irrelevant to this question.

```
<div class="cover-container">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
<div>
```

And this is my CSS. This should make the background image take up the entire container width.

```css
.cover-container {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
}

.cover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

And then we adjust the height of the container to the ratio the width was stretched out or squeezed:

```js
let resizeCover = size => {
  const [w, h] = size;
    const ratio = $cover.width() / w;
  $cover.height(cover.height * ratio);
}

const $cover = $('.cover');
const cover = new Image();
cover.src = url;

let imgSize = null;
cover.onload = () => {
    imgSize = [cover.width, cover.height];
  const bg = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url("' + url + '")';
  $cover.css('background-image', bg);
    resizeCover(imgSize);
};
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k8ny6t0/). It has some content so you can see the fixed scroll effect we want in our cover.

Now, see how there's a grey gap below the background image. If you open the image source you can see it's offset to the top: the gap matches the top part of the image that isn't shown.

[image]

The image used in the fiddle has a 9:1 aspect ratio. The `.cover` width/height ratio is pretty much the same (decimals), you can see it in the log. So it's not like the size of the container isn't matching the image aspect ratio and that's why it's not fitting exactly.

Why is this happening? Why is the image being pushed to the top, creating that gap? It should fit the container perfectly or almost perfectly.

I've tried with `background-size: cover` because [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) say:

> cover
> Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary. If the proportions of the image
> differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or
> horizontally so that no empty space remains.

However, it's clear that the image is stretched out to the window's dimensions, not the container's.

PS: the sole reason I'm not using an `<img>` tag, which would make things much easier and responsive, is that we want the `background-attachment: fixed` effect.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` means the background image gets aligned with regard to the viewport, and you have that combined with `background-position: center top;` …

Comment: @CBroe Where in the docs does it say that it gets aligned to the viewport? In any case, it shouldn't matter because the container is resized after the image's aspect ratio, so it should compensate for that, shouldn't it? Same than your point about `background-position`. If the cover container aspect ratio matches the background image, it shouldn't get shifted around. In fact that whole like could be removed.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment: _“If the background image is fixed within the viewport […] the image is placed relative to the viewport instead of the element's padding box.”_

Comment: _“because the container is resized after the image's aspect ratio, so it should compensate for that, shouldn't it?”_ – no, why? What does the aspect ratio have to do with background placement? Take two DIN A4/Letter sized pieces of paper. Glue one to the wall in front of you (bg-attachment: fixed), move the other around over the wall (“scrolling the document content”). They have the same size and therefor same aspect ratio, but there is only one single position, where they will perfectly overlap.

Comment: And that’s the same situation you got here. Only your two “sheets of paper” don’t perfectly overlap in their initial position to begin with - _because_ the fixed background image is aligned to the top of the viewport, whereas your element is kept a bit from the top, due to the default margin applied to the body element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by just applying the offset as `background-position`:

```js
const offset = $cover.offset().top;
$cover.css('background-position', `0 ${offset}px`);
```

This works because as per the docs, if the background image is fixed it is placed relative to the viewport, not the container.

[Working fiddle.](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/ba6xs2g9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change  [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) `background-attachment: fixed;` to `background-attachment: local;`  or just remove it completlly and `background-size: 100%;` to `background-size: cover;` on the `.cover` element.

> **local** The background is fixed relative to the element's contents. If the element has a scrolling mechanism, the background scrolls with
> the element's contents, and the background painting area and
> background positioning area are relative to the scrollable area of the
> element rather than to the border framing them.

```
.cover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-attachment: local;
}
```

Here is the final result:

```js
//const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618960216830-281234f5f1fc?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1200';
const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620380890341-424d001e03c3?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=900';

const $cover = $('.cover');
let imgSize = null;
const cover = new Image();
cover.src = url;

let resizeCover = () => {
  const [w, h] = imgSize;
    const ratio = $cover.width() / w;
  $cover.height(cover.height * ratio);
  console.log($cover.width() / $cover.height());
}

cover.onload = () => {
    imgSize = [cover.width, cover.height];
  const bg = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url("' + url + '")';
  $cover.css('background-image', bg);
    resizeCover();
};

$(window).resize(() => resizeCover());
```

```css
.cover-container {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
}

.cover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
  /*background-size: 100%;*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  background-attachment: local;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover-container">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
<div>
```

DEMO 2:

```js
//const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618960216830-281234f5f1fc?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1200';
const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620380890341-424d001e03c3?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=900';

const $cover = $('.cover');
let imgSize = null;
const cover = new Image();
cover.src = url;

let resizeCover = () => {
  const [w, h] = imgSize;
    const ratio = $cover.width() / w;
  $cover.height(cover.height * ratio);
  console.log($cover.width() / $cover.height());
}

cover.onload = () => {
    imgSize = [cover.width, cover.height];
  const bg = 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url("' + url + '")';
  $cover.css('background-image', bg);
    resizeCover();
};

$(window).resize(() => resizeCover());
```

```css
.cover-container {
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
}

.cover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45));
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover-container">
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: If you add content above and below the image in the snippet, the image is no longer staying in a fixed position when scrolling

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Just set a height on the the element with the class `cover`.

Comment: As I said I'm trying to get the `fixed` effect. If I change `background-attachment` to `local` or remove it entirely I'm losing it.